# Pivot multiple same columns from single column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here I put the sample data. This is my SQL table, I want to CardNo as Column Heading.Value1 and Value2 as a data for CardNo.

[image: SQL Table Screenshot]

Here is sample output that I created in Excel for question posting but I want to get these through SQL query.

[image: Actual I want output in this manner]

I'm trying to pivot in SQL query but not getting actual output that I need.

Comment: Please don’t post links to images of code/data. Instead, edit your question the include the code/data as formatted plaintext.

Comment: In addition to what Bohemian says, what does your query look like?

Comment: Thanks for quick turnaround..I didn't get this things through query.

Comment: @LukStorms. it was my mistake. by the way cardNo doesn't increase. it remains same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PIVOT.

```
SELECT
 [Date],
 [CardNo],
 CASE WHEN [4] IS NOT NULL THEN [Value1] END AS [4],
 [4],
 CASE WHEN [5] IS NOT NULL THEN [Value1] END AS [5],
 [5],
 CASE WHEN [6] IS NOT NULL THEN [Value1] END AS [6],
 [6]
FROM
(
  SELECT
  [Date], [CardNo], [Value1],
  [SignalType], [Value2]
  FROM YourTable
  WHERE [SignalType] IN (4, 5, 6)  --  Optional. Just for efficiency reasons. By only retrieving what's required.
) Src
PIVOT
(
  MAX([Value2])
  FOR [SignalType] IN ([4], [5], [6])
) Pvt
ORDER BY
 [Date],
 [CardNo],
 [Value1];
```

Comment: Thanks @LukStorms. i'm very close to my solution after referring your answer !!

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select
    date,
    cardno,
    max(case when SignalType = 4 then Value1 end) Value1_4,
    max(case when SignalType = 4 then Value2 end) Value2_4,
    max(case when SignalType = 5 then Value1 end) Value1_5,
    max(case when SignalType = 5 then Value2 end) Value2_5,
    max(case when SignalType = 6 then Value1 end) Value1_6,
    max(case when SignalType = 6 then Value2 end) Value2_6
from mytable
group by date, cardno
```

Note: it is not showing in your expected results, but, most likely, you want the `date` to appear in the `group by` clause. I added it.